# Trouble Accessing and Aggregating a Specific Column within a File

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I need to access a .txt file and add up the integers in all of the last columns using an accumulation pattern. I know I've accessed and opened the file correctly, however, it's the aggregation of the last column that's stumped me. The current code is giving me a 0 (while playing around with it, I've run into a few different errors.)

I'm aware that each line is a string and that I need to split the lines into a list of values in order to continue. Any suggestions/help would be extremely helpful.

```
the_File = open("DoT_Info.txt", "r")
num_accidents = 0
for char in the_File.readlines():
    new_splt = char.split(',')
    num_accidents += int(new_splt[-1])
print('Total Incidents: ', num_accidents)
the_File.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to work, assuming the last element in each row is always the number of accidents.

```
import csv

with open("DoT_Info.txt", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # next(reader) - do this if there is a header row
    num_accidents = sum(int(row[-1]) for row in reader)
    print('Total Incidents: ', num_accidents)
```